# Magento change email address of form

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I bought a magento based website some days ago.
There is a form in the page website.com/service 
the actual code in the backend is:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="serviceForm" form_action="/contacts/index/service" template="contacts/form_service.phtml"}}
```

and in the front-end it is

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" action="/contacts/index/service">
```

It is not exactly a contact form but contact form with lots of additional parameters.
What I want to do is edit the email address the form is submitted to.

If the form action was /contacts/index/post/ I could have edited the file at

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php
```

But I am unable to find any file where I can edit for /contacts/index/service .
I think that the form is working as it tells me

> Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.

after redirecting me to a certain page after form submission.
So I basically want to edit the email and need your help to find the location of the file.

@aynber located the function for me but I can't seem to find the email.

```
public function serviceAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should still be in that file, it will just be `function serviceAction()` inside of IndexController.php. If it's not there, see if there is a corresponding IndexController.php somewhere inside of the app/code/local directory.  Often the forms pull from an email address set in the System configuration under Contacts.

**EDIT**

The line you're looking to change is

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
```

That address is pulled from the system configuration. You can hardcode the email address, or set it to another configured email address.

Comment: Thanks, Updated the post with the serviceAction function but still I can't see a way to edit the email.

Comment: Ok, but I am getting only 4 parameters right now, but originally there are more like 12 .

Comment: I checked with firebug that the actual post is happening for all the parameters.

Comment: Parameters as form fields, or something else? Take a look at the email template you're using to see how it's set up, and make sure it's getting the post fields correctly. The default email contact template can be found under System -> Transactional Emails. If you don't see the contact form, click on Add Template -> Contact Form -> Load Template, and you can add in the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to change the address in the adminpanel at System->Configuration->General->Store Email Adresses

Comment: Thanks,but my current list is empty.